# Using outside variables inside an included file (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, include

My goal is to have multiple sites run off the same files, but have a set of variables that determine which database to access:

```
<?php 

$siteDB = "this";
$domainName = "thisdomain";
$twitterName = "thistwitter";
$facebookName = "thisfacebook";

include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php'; 

?>
```

When I try to access the variables in the `site_files/index.php` they return NULL. I also tried using `$GLOBALS['siteDB']`, but no luck, which didn't surprise me.

I know there are a couple similar questions out there to this one, but I also wanted to ask if this is even the best way to go about doing this. Should I be using some type of configuration file, or session variables?

---

I have my site files organized like:

`www.mysite.com/site1`

`www.mysite.com/site2`

`www.mysite.com/site3`

`www.mysite.com/site4`

---

The files for the sites are located at:

`www.mysite.com/site_files`

---

When the files are updated, and because all sites access the same file, they all update. The file above would be at:

`www.mysite.com/siteX/index.php`

Comment: is the `site_files/index.php` in a local directory on your server, or it is really some external script you are including?

Comment: then simply include it with relative/absolute path `include "site_files/index.php"`

Comment: I don't have an issue including `index.php` from the site_files directory, I need to access the variables that are outside of the included file. For example if in `site_files/index.php` I were to put `echo $domainName`, it would return "thisdomain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting to work by using the absolute URL.

Instead of:

```
<?php 

$siteDB = "this";
$domainName = "thisdomain";
$twitterName = "thistwitter";
$facebookName = "thisfacebook";

include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php'; 

?>
```

---

I was advised to use:

```
<?php 

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site1/config.php'; 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site_files/index.php'; 

?>
```

Where `/site1/config.php` contains:

```
$siteDB = "this";
$domainName = "thisdomain";
$twitterName = "thistwitter";
$facebookName = "thisfacebook";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a configuration file, and include it in your other files.

Example of config file:

```
$config = array('site' => "this",
 'domain' =>  "thisdomain",
  'twitter' => "thistwitter",
 'facebook' => 'thisfacebook'
);
```

Comment: How would I determine which config file to use? Each of the sites would have their own config file, and the site_files' index.php will be accessed by all sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is $GLOBALS['siteDB'] and not $GLOBAL['siteDB']

Comment: Yeah you're right, I changed it. In my code it's $GLOBALS['siteDB'].

Answer (score 0):

As none of the answers explains what the actual problem is, I'll give it a try although the problem is already solved.

When you use:

```
include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php';
```

your server makes an http request to the address `www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php`, just like the browser does when you request a page.

The server on `mysite.com` will simply parse its php and return the result. This result will be included in your script but it will not (likely...) contain php code but the html string that results from `/site_files/index.php`.

If you want to pass variables to the url you are requesting, you could use:

```
include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php?var1=some_value;etc=value';
```

but that is probably not what you want as it would complicate your setup needlessly if all files reside on the same file-system.

Bottom line, if you want to include a php script, don't request it from the web-server but from the file-system.